# What is the correct way to describe language courses based on the level?

Tags: adjective-phrases

I need to explain that there are lessons for beginner/intermediate/advanced learners. Since "beginner" is also a noun, I assume it's correct to say "Spanish lessons for beginners." But how do I go about "advanced" and "intermediate"? Is there a way to describe the lessons without adding the word "learner"? There's not enough space to fit "learners." And without "learners" the phrase "Spanish lessons for advanced" won't be correct, right?

Do these phrases sound natural and are grammatically correct?
**Beginner Spanish lessons

Intermediate Spanish lessons

Advanced Spanish lessons**

Comment: Yes, they do sound natural.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "Beginner/Intermediate/Advanced Spanish Lessons". It is grammatically correct, and sounds idiomatic as well.

Answer (score 1):

The three suggestions that you propose sound natural and are correct, but the grammar is slightly different. "Beginner" is a noun used attributively, while "intermediate" and "advanced" are adjectives. If you wanted to make the phrases more parallel, then you could say:

> Basic Spanish lessons
> Intermediate Spanish lessons
> Advanced Spanish lessons

(I'm being fairly nitpicky. In practice, very few people would notice a difference.)

Comment: Spanish at **Elementary level** and so on.